# NLog - independent loggers for each test in parallel execution

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

I read other threads about parallel logging in tests, but Im still not having any solution for my problem. In my UI tests I have configuration from xml like:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true">

    <targets>
        <target type="File" name="FileA" fileName="${basedir}/Results/FileA-${event-properties:FileId}.txt" layout="${event-properties:item=CreatedOn}  ${event-properties:item=Message}" keepFileOpen="true"/>
        <target type="File" name="FileB" fileName="${basedir}/Results/FileB-${event-properties:FileId}.txt" layout="${event-properties:item=CreatedOn}  ${event-properties:item=Message}" keepFileOpen="true"/>
    </targets>
    
    <rules>
        <logger name="FileA" minlevel="Info" writeTo="FileA" />
        <logger name="FileB" minlevel="Info" writeTo="FileB" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

{event-properties:FileId} = TestContext.CurrentTest.Test.ID(unique key generated for each test)

**Question** -
My all test are executed in parallel and I want to create 2 files for each tests. If I understand this well, my 100 executed tests works with only 2 loggers during parallel execution? Each test doesnt have independent loggers FileA/FileB? Is it possible to have each test with independent loggers in parallel?

**Problem** -
If targets include async="true" one of my file is not ready for sending it to TestContext.AddTestAttachment(file), because its probably in "queue" for logging and I couldn't use LogManager.Flush(), because my one test will get all files from other tests also.

How to resolve this problem?

Method for adding test attachments for each test in Azure Devops.

```
public static void CreateTestAttachments()
        {
            LogManager.Flush();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Results");

            Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(filePath, $"*{FileId}*")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(file => TestContext.AddTestAttachment(file));
        }
```

Comment: What kind of test? In well setup unittests every test would get its own Logging Mock injected and so tests would be independent. But we have no idea what you have. You seem to use a concrete Logger that seems a problem in itself i you want todo unittesting. And if you do integration testing that seems to be a problem in doing them in parallel and you presumably shouldn't do that.

Comment: I fixed my post. Im writing about UI tests. Im not inject Logger instance to each test Im using static method where I execute: var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName); and logger.Log(logEventInfo);

Comment: What is `TestContext.AddTestAttachment(file)` ? There should be nothing wrong with using `async="true"` and `LogManager.Flush()`.

Comment: Is it possible to have each test with independent loggers in parallel? "Yes"

Comment: Thanks for answers :) I had little bug in my code. Async targes and LogManager.Flush() now works as I expected. In TearDown I use CreateTestAttachments method for find all created log file paths per fileId and all created files are added to attachments.

Comment: Before fix I used something like this .EnumerateFiles(filePath), so one of my test got all log files and I was wrong about LogManager.Flush().
During log with async targets all loggers creating separate thread?
For example:
Test1 have FileA and FileB loggers as a separate thread?
Test2 have FileA and FileB loggers as a separate thread?
Does LogManager.Flush() will wait for all queued loggers only in Test1 thread or it wait for all test threads?(This is very important for me).

Comment: LogManager.Flush() will not wait for active application-threads to be done with their logging (it has little knowledge of active application threads). LogManager.Flush() will only ensure the logging-output currently writtten by the application-threads is flushed to the the configured nlog-targets. If you want all output to be included in the flush, then you need to wait for all application-threads to finish first, before calling LogManager.Flush()

Comment: @Rolf Kristensen thanks for detailed answer. :)